# How to make a picture frame with geometry nodes (from 2D profiles)?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

A friend and I are trying to model a frame in order to make a 3D video featuring one of his photos.
After seeing this tutorial: https://youtu.be/hJZRfTAOgk4?t=30 we agreed that it would be easier to work with 2D extruded profiles to form the frame *(screenshot 01)*.
[image: 2D profiles]

However, in order to be able to iterate several designs, I would like to create a modifier able to generate a solid frame with the proportions [w 5.83 x h 7.77], using a simple 2D profile obtained from points/vertices.

I know this may seem tedious for the simple task of modeling a frame on blender, but it is also a way for me to practice with geometry nodes.
Here is what my first attempt did.
[image: 1st attempt]
[image: Geo Nodes tree]

I used the most basic functions and I would like to know if any of you know how to create a mesh from these 4 profiles, once well positioned.
As you can see I simply rotated and translated the original shape from it's origin, then joined it with it's symmetrical copy. (This may lead to nothing but...)

Thanks in advance for your help. I know there are a hundred ways to do what I have in mind and my first experimentation must be one of the worst, but if you know how to proceed, or how to simply do this task and want to help me, I would be very grateful.

Thanks again

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Try `Curve to Mesh` with a `Quadrilateral` as *Curve*.

Comment: @quellenform Thanks. I'm currently trying to figure out where and how to place these nodes. Thank you very much for your help.